# WordPress | Using imagehover on Featured Images

Tags: wordpress, image, hover, thumbnails, wordpress-featured-image

I'm not a a big pro-Pro, but I do know my way around in basic scripting/adjusting/editing and stuff when it comes to CMS. Right now, I'm using WordPress for my website. I modified a theme and all is running quite well (it's in construction mode).

However, there's one thing I've been trying to accomplish, but I can't get it to work.

WordPress has this feature called Featured Image. It's an image/thumbnail you can include to an article. What I'm trying to do here, is to turn that Featured Image into a imagehover. So when people move their mouse over the (black and white) image, it turns into another (colored) image.

One of the things I've been able to figure out, is using a WordPress pluging called Multiple Post Thumbnails. It lets you add 2 Featured Images (thumbnails) to a single article. In this case: a black and white image and a colored image.

Now here's the thing; there in fact can be found some sort of a tutorial on how to activate this modification, but I can't get it to work. URL: http://www.scratchinginfo.net/hover-two-featured-images-wordpress-via-multiple-post-thumbnails-plugin/

So my two questions:

1. Is there a better (easier) way to accomplish this imagehover?
2. As for the tutorial:

I used copy/paste on all code and added it to my own files/theme. All it gave me was a blanc page. I had to remove and adjust some code from the functions.php code (for instance the name of the theme) to get it to work at all (meaning: to be able to show my page at all):

Tutorial:

```
if (class_exists('MultiPostThumbnails')) {
    new MultiPostThumbnails(
        array(
            'label' =&gt; 'Colored Image',
            'id' =&gt; 'colored-image',
            'post_type' =&gt; 'post'
        )
    );
}
```

Only shows up anything like this:

```
if (class_exists('MultiPostThumbnails')) {
new MultiPostThumbnails(
    array(
        'label' => 'Colored Image',
        'id' => 'colored-image',
        'post_type' => 'post'
    )
);
}
```

Like I said, I can't get it to work. Adjusting this piece of code leaves me off where I started. Black and white images (Featured Image 1) only.

I'm using this Cosmox theme: http://cosmox.ozythemes.com/. I created a page with a couple of images/thumbnails (which are the Featured Images) of partners (faces) under each other. When you scroll over those images, a textbox with information is revealed. It's basically the same as the WHATS NEW section.

Hopefully there's a simple solution to this one ;)

Thanks so much!

@dingo_d:

```
foreach( $myposts as $post ) :  the_post(); $more = 0; 
        echo '<li>';
        echo '  <div class="item-wrapper">';
        echo '      <div>';
        if ( has_post_thumbnail() ):
            $upload_dir = wp_upload_dir();
            $custom = get_post_custom(); $custom = get_post_meta($custom["_thumbnail_id"][0]); 
            $custom = unserialize($custom['_wp_attachment_metadata'][0]); $upload_folder = dirname($custom['file']);
            if(isset($custom['sizes']) && !empty($custom['sizes'])) {
                echo '<img src="'.  $upload_dir['baseurl'] . '/' . $upload_folder . '/' .  $custom['sizes']['portfolio-featured-thumb-460']['file'] . '" width="100%"/>';       
            }else{
                echo '<img src="'.  $upload_dir['baseurl'] . '/' . $custom["file"] . '" width="100%"/>';        
            }
        else:
            //no image image
            echo '<img src="' . OZY_BASE_URL . 'images/no-image310x140.png" width="100%"/>';
        endif;
        echo '          <div class="hover"></div>';
        echo '      </div>';
        echo '      <span class="cfnt" align="center">';
                        the_title();
        echo '      </span>';
        echo '  </div>';
        if($xml->description=='1') echo '<div class="desc"><span class="cfnt">' . get_the_title() . '</span><p>' . strip_tags(get_the_content('','')) . '</p></div>';
        echo "</li>";
    endforeach;
```

EDIT 2:

```
echo '<img src="'.  $upload_dir['baseurl'] . '/' . $upload_folder . '/' .  $custom['sizes']['portfolio-featured-thumb-460']['file'] . '" width="100%" class="nohover" /><img alt="imagehover" src="URL TO HOVER IMAGE" class="hover" />';
```

Comment: Couldn't you just use css? Like here for example: http://www.html5templatesdreamweaver.com/hover-effects.html

Comment: Hi, and thank you for your reply.

I did have a look at options using CSS, however I thought it wouldn't work out that well, since I'm using different 'Featured Images'. They're all being called up by the use of one single code in the layouts-objects.php file (from what I can tell).

Have a look at the bottom of my original post. I added the code in the layouts-objects.php file. The Featured Image-part: portfolio-featured-thumb-460.

Comment: From what I can see you have image in the `.item-wrapper` div, after the image is just empty `.hover` div and a span with a title. Here http://www.alessioatzeni.com/wp-content/tutorials/html-css/CSS3-Hover-Effects/index_4.html they use another div under the image that will remove the opacity from the image (`.fourth-effect .mask` and border is used to cover the image).

Comment: I tried to figure out what you were saying, but I guess the info kind of blew me away ;) The image indeed is called from the item-wrapper div (['portfolio-featured-thumb-460']). What did you mean by it being just empty after the image? The 'no image image'-part? And finally: what should I be doing with the .hover div and span (with a title)? I did have a look at the url. Seems nice (if I'm able to use a second image instead of some opacity-percentage). Thanks! :)

Comment: By the way, I was trying to figure out this other option as well. In my original post, at EDIT 2, you can see my modified piece of code (the mid-section with the portfolio-featured-thumb-460). If there was a way to replace the URL TO HOVER IMAGE-part (not just by using a real url, but in the form of a code -like in the first part of that code), that would solve the case as well, right? Calling the (second, hover Featured) image from the Multiple Post Thumbnails-plugin. Hope that makes sense... ;)

Answer (score 0):

From the code above your output should be something like this (in html)

```
<li>
     <div class="item-wrapper">
        <div>
            <img src=""/>       
            <div class="hover"></div>
        </div>
        <span class="cfnt" align="center"></span>
    </div>
        <div class="desc"><span class="cfnt"></span><p></p></div>
</li>
```

Under the image there is an empty div with the class `hover` that you can use in conjuncture with [this](http://www.alessioatzeni.com/wp-content/tutorials/html-css/CSS3-Hover-Effects/index_4.html) effect, to make your image first be black, and then be revealed on hover.

Comment: Thanks again for your reply. I did some tests and however I am now able to make the original 1st Featured Image hover, I can't make it hover with the code from the 2nd Featured Image. PASTEBIN (unaltered code): http://pastebin.com/1vW5R6NW. PASTEBIN (edited code, so I am now able to see a no-image image, which hovers with the 1st Image/thumb): http://pastebin.com/wMyrWw1U. It seems I'm in need for some <img scr=""> code to put between the echo 'NEW CODE FOR 2ND FEATURED IMAGE';. The only code the author of this plugin is talking about on his site is: MultiPostThumbnails::has_post_thumbnail()

Comment: So what I'm basically saying is I'm not looking for this 1st Featured image to be hovered with a stock image or a color (which would be a permanent link/code), but with the 2nd Featured Image which also gets uploaded into the same article/post and has its own code (which I can't seem to put together).